# Working with arrays in C to procedurally generate descriptions, but it's returning a jumbled mess

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to get a very basic framework in place to procedurally generate room descriptions in a game I want to make. However, my descriptions are all jumbled up. I can't figure out why.

Here's the relevant code:

From main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "structs.h"

char RoomDesc[60];

int main()
{
    RoomGen(RoomDesc);
    printf("This room %s ", RoomDesc);

    return 0;
}


void RoomGen(char* RoomDesc) {
srand (time(NULL));
RoomDesc[0]=0; /* Create zero length string,
                  make sure it's cleared out after any previous uses */
/* RoomDesc1 describes the overall appearance of a room, and RoomDesc2
   is if the floor is even, upwards or downwards. "on a" is a connector. */

    strcat(RoomDesc, RoomDesc1[(rand() % 5)]);
    strcat(RoomDesc, "on a ");
    strcat(RoomDesc, RoomDesc2[(rand() % 3)]);
}
```

And this is structs.h:

```
void RoomGen(char *RoomDesc);

char RoomDesc1[30][6] = {
    "is a litter filled mess",
    "is strewn with bones",
    "is almost empty",
    "feels like there is a presence",
    "feels quite warm",
    "feels chilly"
};

char RoomDesc2[14][3] = {
    "upward slope",
    "downward slope",
    "even keel"
};
```

The output should look like: "This room is almost empty on a downward slope."

Instead, it looks like: "This room feels feels on a eve," (Or can vary a bit, since the random part seems to be working, but that's what a test run just now got me.)

I'm getting a ton of warnings on the structs.h portion also. I also tried changing the structs.h definitions to look like:

```
char RoomDesc1[][6] = {
```

But I still get a jumbled description and lots of warnings. 
The warning I'm specifically getting is "warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [enabled by default]" which is odd as I counted out the longest string and set it to be that length. Taking the number away and just leaving [] still produces the same warning.

At this point, I'm kinda stuck. I've spent a half hour looking up how arrays should be formatted, and I can't find anything wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Change `(rand() % 5)` to this `(rand() % 6)`. So you don't leave out `"feels chilly"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RoomDesc1` is not a 2D-array, it's an array of `const char *`

```
const char * RoomDesc1[6] = {
    "is a litter filled mess",
    "is strewn with bones",
    "is almost empty",
    "feels like there is a presence",
    "feels quite warm",
    "feels chilly"
};
```

likewise for `RoomDesc2`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, change declarations to this:

```
char RoomDesc1[6][30] = {
```

...

```
char RoomDesc2[3][14] = {
```

For a detailed explanation of arrays in C and C++, see: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays

Answer (score 0):

RoomDesc[0]=0; will only clear 0th byte for the array.
to clear whole array you should use memset function

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using repeated calls to strcat - it keeps having to search for the terminating '\0' before concatenating, thus getting slower and slower (this is an example of a Shlemiel the Painter algorithm). Instead use snprintf:

```
int maxSize = 60;
snprintf( RoomDesc, maxSize, "%s on a %s", RoomDesc1[(rand() % 5], RoomDesc2[(rand() % 3)]);
```